# Find UserPrincipals where name is empty

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I want to return all UserPrincipals that do not have a name.

Using this code:

```
List<UserPrincipal> searchPrinciples = new List<UserPrincipal>();
searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(ctx) { Name = null });
```

Gives me an error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Principal.Name cannot be null or empty.
```

I get the same error when using this search parameter:

```
 searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(ctx) { Name = ""});
```

Comment: can you show how your `UserPrincipal` and `Principal` looks like

Comment: According to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.name(v=vs.110).aspx) you can't set that property to null. How are you searching the AD for users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set `UserPrincipal.Name` to `null`, according to the specification: [(Principal.Name)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.name(v=vs.110).aspx)

> 'Principal.Name' is the name of the principal or null if the name attribute is not set.
>
> [...] Throws 'ArgumentNullException' if the application tries to set the name to null.

If you want it to be null (or empty), just don't set it all. It'll be initialized to null by default.

If you want to search all the `UserPrincipal` instances that have a null name, you can do something like this (LINQ):

```
IEnumerable<UserPrincipal> result = searchPrinciples.Where(p => String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name));
```